# Removing multiple layers of paint on oak decorative door frames

Tags: wood, staining

I'm making headway. I keep re-applying, scraping (plastic and steel wool), and wiping with mineral spirits. I have all low voc, etc., chemicals but how much can the little grooves in this wood really take?

Also, on the one flat side I stripped, it looks dull (I'm not sure if 'cloudy' would apply) even tho' I wiped it down with spirits nice. Is this normal?

The previous 1930's stain is showing thru, lighter in some places.  I'm psyched because it's gorgeous. I would like it darker. Do I have to strip THAT off or can I just go over it with stain.

Thank you.

Pls create better tags for me.  I'm new.

Comment: Hi Patti, welcome to StackExhange. If you want to get into a discourse about how to go about what you're doing a normal forum would be a better bet for you, SE is a strict question-and-answer site where narrowly focussed Questions get on-point Answers that try to be canonical for the subject, so there are no repeats. We have many previous Q&As that touch on stripping, stain etc. if you want to search for more on each subject. On the basics of removing the paint though, if you're not using a purpose-made stripper you're making this much harder on yourself than it needs to be.

Comment: So glad I asked.  Thank you.